# Proof that expression is positive if conditions is met

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing

Is there a way to show that this expression is always positive as long as $b>0$ and $r>x$ ? Assume $r>0$ and $x>0$
\begin{equation}
b-1+\sqrt{(1+b)^2-\frac{4rb}{x}}
\end{equation}

It's simple with $b>1$ but I can't figure it out if it is true for lower values.

Comment: Just prove $\sqrt{(1+b)^2-\frac{4rb}{x}} \gt 1- b$

Comment: If $b > 0$ then $(1+b)^2 > 1$.  if $r>x$... hmm.  Are we told $x > 0$ ?  If so $r/x > 0$ and $(1+ b)^2 - 4xb/x > (1+b)^2 - 4b = 1 - 2b + b^2 = (1-b)^2$.  Can you go from there.

Comment: The expression inside the square root can be made negative by taking $r$ extremely large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is obviously not true if $(1+b)^2 - \frac {4br}x < 0$.

Case 1:  $(1+b)^2 - \frac {4br}x < 0$ or in other words

$(1+b)^2 < \frac {4br}x$ or

$\frac {(1+b)^2*|x|}{4|b|} < r$.  (Assuming $b \ne 0$.  If $b = 0$ then $(1+b)^2 - \frac {4br}x = (1+b)^2 = 1$.)

The statement is false and yields non-real number.

Case 2:

$(1+b)^2 - \frac {4br}x = 0$ or $r =\frac {(1+b)^2*|x|}{4|b|}$

In this case $b-1 + \sqrt{(1+b)^2 - \frac {4br}x} = b-1 > 0 \iff b > 1$

Case 3:$r <\frac {(1+b)^2*|x|}{4|b|}$

$b-1 + \sqrt{(1+b)^2 - \frac {4br}x} > 0 \iff$

$\sqrt{(1+b)^2 - \frac {4br}x} > 1-b$.

Case 3a: This will be true for $b \ge 1$.

If $b < 1$ then this will be true if

$(1+b)^2 - \frac {4br}x > (1-b)^2 \iff$

$1 + b^2 + 2b - \frac {4br}x > 1 + b^2 -2b \iff$

$4b > \frac {4br}x \iff \frac b{|b|} > \frac rx$

Case 3b: $1> b > 0$ then true if $|x| > r$

Case 3c: $-1< b < 0$ then this is true if $0 > -|x| >r$

So given $b > 0$ and $r > x > 0$ we must have $b \ge 1$ and $x< r \le\frac {(1+b)^2x}{4b}$ or in other words $1 < \frac rx \le \frac{(1+b)^2}{4b}$.

But if $b = 1$ we have $1 < \frac rx \le 1$ so $b > 1$.  But we must also have the condition  $x< r \le\frac {(1+b)^2x}{4b}$.

Comment: Have you seen my counterexample?  Even though we have $stuff \ge 0$ and $0 < b \le 1$, the inequality is still *false*.

Comment: Yeah.. Not exactly seeing were my error is. $1.1^2 - .6 > 1.1^2 - .4$ ... Oh, god!  That was stupid!!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is *false*.  Consider $b = \frac{1}{10}, x = 1, r = \frac32$.  Clearly, we have $b,x,r>0$ and $r>x$.

$$\sqrt{(1+b)^2-\frac{4rb}{x}} = \sqrt{\left(1+\frac{1}{10}\right)^2-\frac{4(3/2)(1/10)}{1}} = \sqrt\frac{121-60}{100} = \frac{\sqrt{61}}{10}$$

$$b-1+\sqrt{(1+b)^2-\frac{4rb}{x}} = -\frac9{10} + \frac{\sqrt{61}}{10} = \frac{\sqrt{61}-\sqrt{81}}{10} < 0$$

Comment: Oh, nice counter-example! Thanks